# Пытаюсь установить POCO по инструкции с оф. сайта

Tags: c++, windows, install, poco

Пытаюсь установить POCO по инструкции с сайта
https://pocoproject.org/download.html (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pocoproject/poco/poco-1.10.1-release/README - более подробная).
Стоит Visual Studio

Вроде как установил до этого CMake. Выполнил две команды по инструкции (`mkdir cmake-build` и `cd cmake-build`). При выполнении команды cmake .. пишется:
*CMake Error: The source directory "C:/dev" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.*
Особо ничего другого не пробовал, тк инфы в интернете не нашел другой по установке. Очень слабо понимаю, что происходит, так что возможно тупая ошибка.

Comment: Язык C++ если нужен

Comment: ну так проверьте, есть ли у Вас файл CMakeLists.txt в каталоге dev.

Comment: Его нет, но что в таком случае нужно сделать? Установить CMake в другую папку?

Comment: не, если этого файла нет, значит либо не то распаковали, либо не там ищите. я посмотрел, вроде в архиве, который с гитхаба можно скачать оно там есть. Поищите внимательно

Comment: Спасибо, получилось. Но при вводе команды make -s -j пишет "make" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: следующая команда

Comment: там есть приписка, что если Вы используете windows, то скорее всего проект от visual studio и Вам нужно прост открыть в студии солюшн и билдить как обычно. В винде обычно make нет.

Comment: @KoVadim, не нужно ничего открывать, у CMake есть команда `cmake --build`, `cmake --install`. Таким образом он сам решит как собрать проект, и ничего открывать не придется, и возиться с лишними командами типа `make && make install`, or `ninja && ninja install`, `nmake && nmake install`, etc.

Comment: да, я знаю об этой команде. и если бы дело было под линуксом, я бы ее и рекомендовал. Но я не уверен, что оно нормально отработает в обычной консоли (без спец батника для поднятия правильного компиляторного окружения).